# Android: Is there any way to animate fragment deletion in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, cursor, android-viewpager

I've implemented a cursor backed ViewPager, where I'd like to enable the user to add or remove items. However, deleting a page causes janks in the viewpager.

I'm currently manually scrolling to the next page using `viewPager.setCurrentItem(NEXT_PAGE_NO, true);` after deletion and scrolling back in the adapter after updating the data set. This does work, but only half of the time.

Is there any proper way to animate it? A solution or a workaround, both will do.

Comment: Just an idea...Create a flip Animation for the entire ViewPager. So scale it horizontally to zero in an animation, change your fragments, then scale it back to 100%.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but sadly only horizontal swiping fits my design.